# Check if cell is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, cell

As I'm new to Google Apps Script I'm struggling with the understanding of what and how thing done there.
I want to change the color of a cell IF it is empty and two other cells in other columns are empty as well. IF one of them has value, that's OK and should left without any color.

In this screen shot, only rows 5, 6 and 7 need to be colored:

[image: SO54747074 question example]

Meaning the use of a script while running, to check where there is missing values on givens columns ( Email / Main Phone etc ).

Comment: Your question isn't very clear and it doesn't agree with your screen shot. The last sentence suggests that you just want to color rows green if they are totally empty.  If you really want an answer I'd suggest restating your question and trying to solve it with a little code of your own.  Otherwise, it will most likely be closed.

Comment: I didn't stated that and I don't know why you assume I want to color them in green.
Very simply - if all 3 cells in the same row are empty - color it ( doesn't really mind the color itself ), otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

Your question doesn't specify which columns, so based upon the image I presume you want columns C,F and G.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var dflt='#ffffff';
  var fill='#ffff00';
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Sheet69'){return;}//you need to add your sheet name so that this only works on the appropriate sheets
  var ss=e.source;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getMaxRows(),sh.getMaxColumns());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var bA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vA[i][2] && !vA[i][5] && !vA[i][6]){
      for(var j=0;j<bA[i].length;j++) {
        bA[i][j]=fill;
      }        
    }else{
      for(var j=0;j<bA[i].length;j++) {
        bA[i][j]=dflt;
      }     
    }
  }
  rg.setBackgrounds(bA);
}
```

- [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/)

Comment: Sorry for late response - yes, the given columns can change depends on the demand itself so basically what I did is just adding the columns name I want to check and add it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do app scripts to get the effect you want. I have created a dummy test, see if that works for you. It is in "view" mode because... well... internet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ozOITqXNwtvYYmulJV6nrs3MB6SlsRAF8l9a8ImXZkg/edit?usp=sharing

I created a custom formula for cell formatting for the range cell you want the formatting on, not the entire row (probably too much work for the sheet engine).

Select the range you want to apply formatting to, then choose conditional formatting from the menu.
"Format cells if" for my example is set to "Custom formula is" and the value is =AND(ISBLANK($C2),ISBLANK($D2),ISBLANK($E2))

You can copy this formula to any other cells you wish the formatting to appear, giving the appearance of the whole row being formatted.

[image]

Comment: Do I need to apply this formula on each cell? or one is enough?
I wanted to use the GAS but I couldn't even find a way to reach that..

Also, isn't isBlank() function is returning true or false based on the entire column ?

Comment: You would apply it to all cells that require the formatting (it is a sort-of visual hack).

Originally I had it on one cell then copied it, and it didn't work, but that was before I added the $dollar sign and then it did work. I made another test and selected the entire range first and it still worked fine. What you essentially saying is:- "format this cell on this row, if the corresponding cells in columns in B,C and D are all blank".

The IsBlank is returning true for only that cell, the dollar sign just means that the Column value will be locked when copying the formula.

Comment: Can I have for example this formula based on the screenshot I've posted?

Comment: GAS is a bit overkill for this type of requirement, and you would need to hook into onload and onchange events for the sheet to apply formatting without having it attached to a cell.

Your formula would be =AND(ISBLANK($C2),ISBLANK($F2),ISBLANK($G2)). This assumes that you are starting your formula from the second row and copying down.

Comment: Hey, yeah I did got it to work.
Still waiting for someone might maybe give me the answer thru GAS :)